# Adobe keeps scrolling on its own... or else

Tags: pdf, mouse, adobe-acrobat, scrolling, adobe-reader

I am having serious issues with the adobe acrobat reader for Windows 10. I have uninstalled and installed it many times, tried different settings, but nothing works.

I start by downloading the latest version for the Windows 10 operating system. (There is only one option available, namely "Reader DC 2020.009.20063 English for Windows".)

When I try to open then a file, it takes ages for it to open. This apparently is already a very common issue, where the solution is to go to Edit->Preferences->Security(Enhanced) and disable 'Protected mode at startup' and 'Enhanced Security', then restart the application.
(Source: https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/adobe-reader-dc-suddenly-slow/td-p/10421852?page=1)

While this used to solve the issue with previous versions, with the current version a new issue has appeared that I cannot get rid of unless I go back and enable the security settings.

The issue is that the pdf document will scroll by itself, very slowly. I have already checked whether it was because of the keyboard or the mouse, but when disconnecting either device, the pdf keeps scrolling on its own.

So now I am stuck at either having to wait for ages before the pdf opens, or having the pdf open quickly, but scroll on its own.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong here. I have Adobe Reader DC on one Windows 10 machine and Adobe Acrobat Pro DC on this Windows 10 machine here.  Neither Adobe takes long to open a document and neither scrolls automatically. In Adobe View Tab, make sure Read Mode is off and also Page Display, make sure Scrolling is off. Do an Adobe Repair to help restore default operation.

Comment: Yep. All settings are default. That also means Read Mode is off. Page Display is set to 'Enable scrolling', since that is what I want. The issues also do not appear on every windows 10 machine I have.

Comment: I think the scrolling mode you want may be causing the scrolling on the screen.

Comment: No. The scrolling mode allows me to scroll through the document. But when I give no input, it keeps scrolling very slowly by itself.